# Removing rows with NA in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with 2500 rows. A few of the rows have NAs (an excessive number of NAs), and I want to remove those rows.

I've searched the SO archives, and come up with this as the most likely solution:

```
df2 <- df[df[, 12] != NA,]
```

But when I run it and look at df2, all I see is a screen full of NAs (and s).

Any suggestions?

Comment: `df[ ! is.na( df[, 12] ) , ]`

Comment: Define how many `NA`s per row constitute "an excessive number", then use `rowSums` and `is.na`.

Comment: If an "excessive number" is any .. then `?complete.cases`. Otherwise what Ananda said.

Comment: Right, I should have been more specific about "an excessive number." Actually, based on what I had, I wanted to delete any row with an NA anywhere. I ended up using Simon's method, and it worked. But I need to figure out -- and I will -- how to make it more general. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what you're looking for, one of the following should help you on your way:

Some sample data to start with:

```
mydf <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, NA, 4), B = c(1, NA, 3, 4), 
                   C = c(1, NA, 3, 4), D = c(NA, 2, 3, 4), 
                   E = c(NA, 2, 3, 4))
mydf
#    A  B  C  D  E
# 1  1  1  1 NA NA
# 2  2 NA NA  2  2
# 3 NA  3  3  3  3
# 4  4  4  4  4  4
```

If you wanted to remove rows just according to a few specific columns, you can use `complete.cases` or the solution suggested by @SimonO101 in the comments. Here, I'm removing rows which have an `NA` in the first column.

```
mydf[complete.cases(mydf$A), ]
#   A  B  C  D  E
# 1 1  1  1 NA NA
# 2 2 NA NA  2  2
# 4 4  4  4  4  4
mydf[!is.na(mydf[, 1]), ]
#   A  B  C  D  E
# 1 1  1  1 NA NA
# 2 2 NA NA  2  2
# 4 4  4  4  4  4
```

If, instead, you wanted to set a threshold--as in "keep only the rows that have fewer than 2 `NA` values" (but you don't care which columns the NA values are in--you can try something like this:

```
mydf[rowSums(is.na(mydf)) < 2, ]
#    A B C D E
# 3 NA 3 3 3 3
# 4  4 4 4 4 4
```

On the other extreme, if you want to delete *all* rows that have *any* `NA` values, just use `complete.cases`:

```
mydf[complete.cases(mydf), ]
#   A B C D E
# 4 4 4 4 4 4
```